# MediaRecorder ondataavailable work successfully once

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, web-mediarecorder

MediaRecorder ondataavailable work successful once.
I need to get blob, get it base64, send to my server, decode this base64 to audio blob.
This is very strange.

For example, output:

blob1
blob2
blob3
blob4
blob5
blob6
blob7
blob8
blob9

....

I can hear just blob1, other blobs is "disabled".

Try it!
This code record audio:

```js
window.startRecord = function(cb){
  var int;
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true , video:false}).then(function(stream){
    var options = {
      audioBitsPerSecond : 128000,
      videoBitsPerSecond : 2500000,
      mimeType : 'audio/webm\;codecs=opus'
    }

    if(!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options['mimeType'])) options['mimeType'] =  "audio/ogg; codecs=opus";


    window.voice = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

    voice.start(500);
    voice.ondataavailable = function(data){


      var reader = new FileReader();
      var blob = data.data;

      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        var result = reader.result;

        cb(result);
      }
    };

    voice.onstop = function(){
      console.log('stop audio call');
    }
  });
}

window.convertDataURIToBinary = function(dataURI) {
  var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
  var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
  var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
  var raw = window.atob(base64);
  var rawLength = raw.length;
  var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

  for(i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
    array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

```html
<body>
<button onclick="startRecord(function(r){
 
    var binary= convertDataURIToBinary(r);
  var blob=new window.Blob([binary], {type : 'audio/webm'});
  var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  console.log('URL : ' + blobUrl);

  document.getElementById('data').append(blobUrl + `

 | 

    `);
   })">Exec</button>

   <div id="data">
     
   </div>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: I tried this same exact thing and the TLDR is use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API to achieve live voice chat

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure what is the problem you try to highlight, but:

The `dataavailable` event's `data` property contains only a *chunk* of the whole data that has been recorded.
For instance, only the first *chunk* will contain the metadata needed for the final recorded media.

It is then expected that you will merge all these chunks together at the time you will export them.

And this should be done only once, at the `MediaRecorder.stop` event.

```
const chunks = []; // store all the chunks in an array
recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
// merge the chunks in a single Blob here
recoder.onstop = e => export_media(new Blob(chunks));
```

Comment: can we somehow extract metadata from first chunk and add it to every other chunk, Actually I am using it for realtime recording so I can't use it just on recorder.onStop()

Comment: @AliSajid there is a very small chance it could work, but I wouldn't bet a cent on it, and even less on it working everywhere in a future proof way. Waht is eactly your use case? You can always just concat all the chunks so that you get an always playable media. You can even pass these chunks to a MediaSource. The important part is that the decoder has all the necessary data to be able to navigate through the file.

Comment: I am recording audio and at the same time posting those chunks on server so that others can hear it

Comment: So you would need to update your file on server in  real-time too.`

Comment: And what about sending it to other clients? I can't send whole file every time to each and every client. I wan't to send chunks to other clients through socket.io. My scenario is somewhat voice chat

Comment: @AliSajid then just use a turn/ice server, and stream the MediaStream directly. To then split it to multiple clients, you can use something like [janus-gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) to create a one-to-many config. Also, if your server can handle range requests, the simple update the recorded file on the fly may also work.

Comment: @Kaiido, I have a much simpler use case. I need to record a 30 second video. While recording, I want to show what is being recorded (only video part). After the recording stopped, the user will have another opportunity to preview the video including the audio before uploading. Acting in front of camera for 30 seconds blindly is not good. How can I achieve this real-time live preview (without sending chunks to a streaming server and loading them back)?

Comment: @Breddy you can simply set the srcObject of a <video> to the stream you are recording.

Comment: @Kaiido, Thank you very much. I have it working now.